# How to create class from string and call method of it?

Tags: c#

I am trying to receive a string input and integer input from a user and then use those inputs to call a method with a specific parameter. 
For example:

```
string object_name   = Dog;
int method_parameter = 5;

object_name.Bark(method_parameter);
```

Here is the actual code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your First Name. ");
string namez = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 to sign in or 2 to sign out. ");
int ez = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Pin.");
int inpu_pin = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (ez == 1)
    namez.OnSignIn(inpu_pin);
if (ez == 2)
    namez.OnSignOut(inpu_pin);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! You should improve your qustion a bit. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further info on how to ask a good question and improve chances for recieving answers instead of downvotes/closevotes. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way is to make use of [Factory method pattern](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2018/05/factory-design-pattern-with-generics.html) can return you object.

```
public class Factory
{
  public static object GetAnimal(string objectName)
  {
    if(objectName == "Dob")
     return new Dog();
    else(objectName == "xyz")
     return new xyz(); 
  } 
}
```

or you can create parent interface for all animal type and return value of factory should be that interface type instead of object.

and then do like this

```
  // reflection
  Object obj = Factory.GetAnimal(args[0]).GetType(); //args[0]="Dog"
  obj.GetMethod("Bark").Invoke(obj,  new object[]{ int.Parse(args[1] });
```

---

you have to make use of reflection and have to do like this

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(string className)
```

or if you know fully qualified name do like this

```
string typeName = args[0]; //"Dog";
string formTypeFullName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", this.GetType().Namespace, typeName);
Type type = Type.GetType(formTypeFullName, true);
Dog dog = (Dog)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
dog.Bark(int.Parse(args[1]));
```

Comment: @DanielSmith - you want to create instance of object from string and then you want to run method on it, that you need to do make to use relfection create object and call method that what i provided in answer, let me know what you are not getting

Comment: I am sure it will work but I can't understand it yet.

Comment: @DanielSmith - updated answer , so you can understand also suggest google reflection in .net C# you will get lot of post to understand function used here in my code

Comment: @DanielSmith What you are doing is possible and this answer shows the solution, but the problem is that you should not write code like that. Calling method by string is not a good solution. You should probably check the value of the string in `if` statement and then call object's method.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: why there is - 1?

Comment: @DanielSmith - you cannot upvote as your points are too less but you can accept answer if works for you

Comment: @FCin - updaed my answe rmight make some sense

Comment: You can completely get rid of reflection by using interface. This question seems to come from a beginner, so I don't think using reflection helps them learn the language.

Comment: I am a beginner.

Comment: @FCin - he is beginner, but there is no way to create object from string except reflection, right ? i think he started on language so he should be aware that he can create object directly and calll it , if i am correct

Comment: @DanielSmith - you know the basics of C# , right ? how to create object and call method ?, if yes then i think you know what you are asking, because as per my knowledge of C# you can create object from string using reflection , there is no other way

Comment: @FCin - reflection is very important concept in .net C#, i think if you are starting on language you should start learning that also..

Comment: @FCin - if you know better solution then you should put answer , that help OP to learn things ,

Comment: I was just thinking of the intention of this question. I think that the problem is not with calling the method from string, but with the approach to the problem. There should be no need for calling method from string in the first place. I just felt like an answer should provide a different path, more natural for the language, than a solution to the exact problem pointed in the question.

Comment: I'm making an Employee Time Clock. Where you enter a pin and the timer starts ticking. And when you sign out it stops and tracks the amount of time you worked.

Comment: @FCin - understood you , you should put your solution , which make some sense ,

Comment: @FCin - hope you like to revert you -1 point ..as there is no other solution apart from the solution given...

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, but someone downvoted mine from 1 year ago about similar issue, so I guess somebody has different opinions about this topic. Also, I don't think your answer is bad, it is valid and I very rarely downvote answers that provide valid solution and description.